# My discord bot doesn't join voice channels, but it doesnt give me any error messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Im making a discord bot in javascript for a server, I need it to join a voice channel when it starts but the code just doesn't work. It has the needed permisions, but it doesnt do anything, there isnt even an error message
This is the code (In channelId and guildId I just used the actual id of the channel i needed and the guild I needed) :

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const VoiceDiscord= require("@discordjs/voice");
const Client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers
    ]
});

Client.once("ready",() => {
    const connection =VoiceDiscord.joinVoiceChannel({
        channelId: 980878176928550912,
        guildId: 980878092849528832,
        adapterCreator: Client.guilds.cache.find(guild => guild.id == 980878092849528832).voiceAdapterCreator
    })
});
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling discord.js and @discordjs/voice, I tried using another bot and it also didnt work

Comment: I'm pretty sure the ids should be strings. Not sure if this would affect your problem, but it's probably worth the shot.

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesn't seem to work either

Answer (score 0):

Your event listener never fires because it should be `Client.on` and not `Client.once`. Your correct code looks like:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const VoiceDiscord= require("@discordjs/voice");
const Client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers
    ]
});

Client.on("ready",() => {
    const connection =VoiceDiscord.joinVoiceChannel({
        channelId: 980878176928550912,
        guildId: 980878092849528832,
        adapterCreator: Client.guilds.cache.find(guild => guild.id == 980878092849528832).voiceAdapterCreator
    })
});
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either, and I putted a console.log in both Client.on and Client.once, they both work